# How can division on Natural numbers be a poset?

Tags: order-theory

For natural numbers including 0, how can it be a poset while zero cannot divide zero. Doesn't this mean it isn't reflexive?

Comment: Who said that $0$ does not divide $0$?

Comment: isn't 0 divide 0 undefined?

Comment: @SebastianSantana You are confusing "division" with "divisibility".

Comment: To see whether $a$ divides $b$, you do not check $b/a$, you check whether $b = ka$ for some $k$.

Comment: The fraction $\frac{0}{0}$ is indeed undefined, but $0$ does divide $0$, for there is an $x$ such that $(0)(x)=0$. There are many such $x$, but that's OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a$ divides $b$ simply means: There is a $k$, s.t. $ak=b$.

Of course $0\cdot 0 = 0$, so $0$ divides $0$.

Comment: Oh dear Jesus, mathematics is so interesting but I'm so dumb.

Comment: Not dumb. Mathematics is all about discovery. You just discovered something. That's how it works!

Comment: @Sebastian Santana That's unlikely, you just have to adjust your intuition all the time.

Comment: Yeah. It's such a drag getting smarter.

Answer (score 0):

I think some of your confusion might be coming from whether or not zero "counts" as a natural number. The natural numbers ${\mathbb N}$ can be used to mean either:
$${\mathbb N}^0:=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$$
or
$${\mathbb N}^{\ast}:=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}.$$
Typically, when one refers to the "natural numbers as a poset order by division", they're referring to ${\mathbb N}^{\ast}$. Although you could define a poset on ${\mathbb N}^0$ with $a\;|\;0$ for all $a\in{\mathbb N}^0$, if you really wanted to include zero in there.

Comment: Either set can be ordered using "divides". One will have a largest element, the other will not.

Comment: I disagree... This isn't really the issue and I don't think, that this is typical.

Comment: Nope, I'm considering the one including 0